# plot manually supplied values in a pane - Pine-Script:TradingView

Tags: pine-script

might there be a way to have a pane that plots number/date pairs that I manually supply (example:[05/24/2021 09:00, 27.8],[05/25/2021 09:00, 31.2],[05/26/2021 09:00, 30.1],[05/27/2021 09:00, 28.3], etc...), instead of plotting data sourced from price, ema, rsi, etc?  I can use labels to daily place my number along the price action, but that doesn't give me a visualization like having them plotted against their own scale, to correlate with price action in the other pane.  Any help, ideas, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this if you're staying with one timeframe and arrange your data simply as comma separated values for that timeframe. You could expand on it and use a second array with `array.from()` to store timestamps for the corresponding value array.

```
var int index = na

start_ts = timestamp(2021, 5, 21)
if time >= start_ts and time[1] < start_ts
    index := 0
else if time > start_ts
    index += 1
    
var prices = array.from(38000, 39000, 40000, 41000)

to_plot = time >= start_ts and index <= array.size(prices) - 1

plot(to_plot ? array.get(prices, index) : na)
```

The simplest approach would be to generate your CSVs for each timeframe you want to work with, then you only need to have the start date/time. It could become quite difficult, though not impossible to work from one master array of low timeframe values. You are also restricted to an array size of 100,000. So that will limit your ability to render higher timeframes. ie <70 days of 1 minute data. You will also need to be careful of the script character limit, especially using multiple CSV arrays.

Comment: R.P.D., TYVM for such a quick contribution to my quest !!!!!
I plugged in your code and it displayed instantly an example.
Two followup Qs though...
1)  Any way for it to populate in it's own pane, instead of atop the price action pane? it condenses the price action into a flat line because of the disparity of the value ranges.
2)  The plotted line seems to be visible on multiple time intervals, up to 3HR ...at 4HR it ceases to be visible.

Comment: Change the study parameter for overlay to show in it's own pane `study("Manual Data", overlay = false)` So the example code above assumes daily interval data. It just starts at the beginning of 21st of May 2021. It then just plots a new value each new bar. If you wanted to use say, fifteen minute data on the fifteen minute chart you'd have something like `start_ts = timestamp(2021, 5, 21, 0, 0)` instead. Check the ref manual for the `timestamp()` function

Comment: awesome  :-)  TYVM

Comment: Oh, it might not be that it ceases to be visible on lower timeframes, that start date may be way back from the time range that is visible on your chart. If you scroll left enough you'd probably find it. Sorry, you may also need to change the `if` statement to `if time >= start_ts and time[1] < start_ts`